# VBA to convert text to columns in multiple sheets except one

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I am new in VBA coding and and am trying to convert text in all sheets except one to text but have not achieved success. I have text in column A of each sheet and number of rows might differ.

This is what my code looks like

```
Sub text_to_column()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr() As Variant, i As Long, nrCol As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            ws.Select
            nrCol = 20
            ReDim arr(1 To nrCol) As Variant
            For i = 1 To nrCol
            arr(i) = Array(i, 1)
            Next
            Selection.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range("A1"), _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, _
            Space:=False, _
            Other:=True, _
            OtherChar:="^", _
            FieldInfo:=arr, _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End If
    Next ws

    End Sub
```

Please Guide.

Comment: Hello. Give us examples of the data (the input) and the desired output. And you didn't mention what is the problem in your code.

Comment: i need to convert text into columns.  The text is in column A of each sheet. And i get a run time error at the time of running my code.  The code reads out as no data was selected to parse.                                                                                                                 The input data i s in format of "4^DD^1^1^1^O^^1^^AAAAA1088G^^^XYZ PVT LTD^1808.00^0.00^0.00^1808.00^^1808.00^^^90422.00^14052018^14052018^^2.0000^^^^^^^94C^^^^^^^^^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, ws As Worksheet, r As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        For r = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            x = Split(ws.Cells(r, 1).Value, "^")
            ws.Cells(r, 2).Resize(, UBound(x) + 1).Value = x
        Next r
    End If
Next was
End Sub
```

And as for your approach, you can use such a code

```
Sub TextToColumns()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next was
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. This works. Can you let me know what was the problem in my code.

Comment: Thankyou. Real Help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I can offer some help. Mark the answer as solved.